# Should I keep some trees?

Tags: simcity-2013

Maps are naturally populated with trees in a new city location, but I haven't yet found a way to add trees back to the location without placing parks and other "buildings".

Should I do my best to build around natural trees? Do they benefit my city by increasing land value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not yet know whether the forest is anything but cosmetic, but from the land value map it looks like the trees do not do much of anything, although in SimCity 4 wild vegetation was an important tool for increasing desirability.

To plant or cut-down the forest one needs to select *Parks > Nature (§§)* then scroll to the right where they would find the tools for the job, as seen on the screenshot below.

> There is no immediate reaction to the use of the tool (except for the money leaving one’s account in an instant, much like EA pre-order), but I suppose it grows over time (much like Origin’s delivery of pre-ordered titles on release day). That said, try as I may, I had not had any tree show up anywhere I had planted, so this tool still needs figuring out.

The above quote is wrong, trees do show up immediately, but not always. Still do not know if it is a feature or a bug.

[image]

Apologies for strange and foreign tongue as per interface. I am yet to figure out how to change it for demonstration purposes.

Comment: According to [this post](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/107714), forests reduce pollution

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft, I know it has been discussed (here too, check the comments to the second answer), but no one showed the evidence just yet, and I have not experienced it (again, cause I did not have as much pollution). So until it is known for sure, I’m not going to assume anything.

Comment: @theUg my trees vs air pollution has failed.  In SimCity 4, trees eat air pollution.  In SimCity 2013, air pollution eats trees.

Comment: @DavidB, I am not sure if it’s air or soil pollution, but I did notice that trees I had planted downwind from the factory (also in the zone of soil pollution) rarefied and eventually disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

They help against air pollution. You might have to replant them several times to get the air pollution to a level the trees can thrive with/accept.

Answer (score 1):

Forests accelerate repair of [ground pollution](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/107759/how-can-i-fix-ground-pollution/108875#108875), and will die over time. They do not consume all ground pollution, so trees need to be replanted.