# Is there a way to fix air pollution in simcity?

Tags: simcity-2013

I've noticed that wind direction changes in the game and now my town is directly downwind from my industrial area, causing pollution and zombie attacks. Is there a way to get rid of the pollution? I'm already at the highest tech level for the industry, but my PPM are still significant.

Comment: Wind can change directions... oh man I'm screwed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the toolbar at the bottom, click the `Tree` icon and plant some forests down wind of the factories. The trees will clean the air.

Comment: Are these the "Nature Parks" or the actual trees with the radial dropper?

Comment: I think you can use the cheap "Plant Forest" dropper which costs $50 per forest. It's at the far right in the "Nature" tab. You can also try planting the narrow row of tree between buildings and see if that helps, but I don't think it's as effective as the forest.

Comment: I attempted to use trees to kill air pollution.  The air pollution killed the trees.

Comment: You need to keep replanting, until the the pollution is low enough for the trees to keep growing. I believe parks will help too.